# Rails better way to get item by field from has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Forgive me if this is a basic question; I'm learning Rails (using 3.2) as I go.

My `Event` model `has_many` `images`. Each image has an `is_primary` boolean field. `Event` should have a `cover_image` method, which returns the image with `is_primary` set to true, or the first image otherwise. This is my code:

```
def cover_image
    imgs = self.images
    imgs.each { |i| return i if i.is_primary }
    # If no primary
    return imgs.first
  end
```

I can't help feeling like there's a better way to do it, one that doesn't involve looping through all the elements just to find one.

Comment: yea - i had the same issue, but i fixed it using images.find() but since you are using an `is_primary` field, that won't work.  There IS a better way to do this because each time i iterates - it queries the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with a scope quite easily:

Image model

```
scope :primary, where(:is_primary => true)
```

Event model

```
def cover_image
  images.primary.first
end
```

This is a really basic example that should get you started at least, you'll want to build on it to handle a missing primary image gracefully, for example.

For completeness, you don't *have* to do this as a scope, if you'd prefer you can use where statements directly. Scopes are just really nice for staying DRY:

Event model

```
def cover_image
  images.where(:is_primary => true).first
end
```